# Where does the Doctor go after Demons Run?

Tags: doctor-who

This is probably very obvious but where does the Doctor go after Demons Run? My first thought was that he wanted to rescue Melody but the longer I think about it, the less sense it makes. And why couldn't he take Amy and Rory with him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what happened is that the Doctor took Amy and Rory home, and then proceeded to time travel at least for a short while because of being distraught over the fact that Amy's child is River Song and that they lost her.

This excerpt is from the [Doctor Who list of prequels for season 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_(series_6)#Prequels) showing evidence supporting this theory as well as showing that the prequel to "Let's Kill Hitler" is indeed canon..

> On 15 August 2011, the BBC released a short "prequel" to "Let's Kill Hitler", written by Steven Moffat. In the prequel, Amy calls the Doctor and leaves a message for the Doctor on the TARDIS's answer phone, begging him to find her child, Melody. Though Amy knows Melody will grow up to be River Song, she does not want to miss seeing her grow up. As she ends her message, it is revealed that a very upset Doctor was listening but did not pick up the phone, even though Amy had pleaded for him to

In the beginning of the episode of "Let's Kill Hitler" the Ponds get the attention of the Doctor using crop circles, so he's obviously either looking for Melody by himself or trying to not think about it for the time being.

Comment: The Hitler prequel is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRqG64hDs4s (and it looks like it's an official BBC upload).

Comment: The Doctor says "River, get them all home" before leaving in the TARDIS, so its implied that she took the Ponds back using her vortex manipulator.